# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be one of type string, TypedArray, or DataView

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

Trying to index some data in elasticsearch using AWS Lambda.
Stack Trace

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be one of
>   type string, TypedArray, or DataView
>       at new Hmac (internal/crypto/hash.js:84:11)
>       at Object.createHmac (crypto.js:122:10)
>       at Object.hmac (/home/projects/serverless-todo-app/.webpack/service/src/indexer/createIndex.js:698:30)
>       at Object.getSigningKey (/home/projects/serverless-todo-app/.webpack/service/src/indexer/createIndex.js:7109:8)
>       at V4.signature (/home/projects/serverless-app/.webpack/service/src/indexer/createIndex.js:12708:36)
>       at V4.authorization (/home/projects/serverless-app/.webpack/service/src/indexer/createIndex.js:12703:36)
>       at V4.addAuthorization (/home/projects/serverless-app/.webpack/service/src/indexer/createIndex.js:12645:12)
>       at ElasticsearchService.put (/home/projects/serverless-app/.webpack/service/src/indexer/createIndex.js:8150:12)
>       at process (/home/projects/serverless-app/.webpack/service/src/indexer/createIndex.js:8115:24)
>       at BbPromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:567:30)
>       at AwsInvokeLocal.invokeLocalNodeJs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:521:12)
>       at AwsInvokeLocal.invokeLocal (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:152:19)
>   From previous event:
>       at Object.invoke:local:invoke [as hook] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:34:10)

```
const credentials = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS');
let signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(this.request, 'es');
signer.addAuthorization(credentials, new Date());
```

Trying to index some data in elastisearch using AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 3):

You should have an endpoint and have initiated your request. You can do it like below and also check the link pasted after the code.

```
/* == Globals == */
var esDomain = {
    region: 'us-east-1',
    endpoint: 'my-domain-search-endpoint',
    index: 'myindex',
    doctype: 'mytype'
};
var endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint(esDomain.endpoint);
/*
 * The AWS credentials are picked up from the environment.
 * They belong to the IAM role assigned to the Lambda function.
 * Since the ES requests are signed using these credentials,
 * make sure to apply a policy that allows ES domain operations
 * to the role.
 */
var creds = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS');

var req = new AWS.HttpRequest(endpoint);

    req.method = 'POST';
    req.path = path.join('/', esDomain.index, esDomain.doctype);
    req.region = esDomain.region;
    req.headers['presigned-expires'] = false;
    req.headers['Host'] = endpoint.host;
    req.body = doc;

    var signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(req , 'es');  // es: service code
    signer.addAuthorization(creds, new Date());
```

In[amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples/blob/master/src/kinesis_lambda_es.js) check lines 45-55
(Sorry I cannot comment because of low reputation)

Comment: thanks it's helped me to solve my problem want to add more thing if any one want to set this locally in their local machine then just set environment variable AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY by using mockedEnv npm modules for process.env as 

var credentials = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS'); required AWS Access key to signing request and it will take from process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID so

Answer (score 1):

Slightly off topic, but I had a very similar stack trace when trying to access a DynamoDB table and stumbled upon this post. So I thought I'd share the problem/solution with others.

Thanks to [D M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3475813/d-m-patel)'s comment, I realised that I was trying to access a DynamoDB table via a client with no credentials set on it. I had already constructed an object of type `AWS.Credentials`, based on credentials I'd got earlier from STS. Something like this:

```
const credentials = new AWS.Credentials({
        accessKeyId: stsCredentials.AccessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: stsCredentials.SecretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: stsCredentials.SessionToken,
      });
```

The bug for me was subtle, because I actually thought I was setting the credentials when constructing the DynamoDB document client:

```
new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(credentials)
```

But actually I had introduced a bug and removed curly braces around the `credentials` object, which were necessary in the structure expected by the `DocumentClient` constructor. So I needed to do:

```
new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({credentials})
```

That was what solved the issue for me.

**Note:** this answer is for the V2 AWS SDK.

Comment: This was a really useful answer: my issue was also related to creds when configuring a DDB method. Completely unrelated to the error code. Thanks for adding this answer!